# C++ SQLite cannot convert `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' to `char*' in assignment

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to use C++ and SQLite but I don'tknow how to pass the parameters into a single string to form the SQLite command.

```
void InsertDB(unsigned long long phone,string name,int age,string address,long int zipcode)
{
stringstream insert;
insert << "INSERT INTO ADBOOK (PHONE,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,ZIPCODE) VALUES (" << phone << ",'" << name << "'," << age << ",'" << address << "'," << zipcode << " ); ";
sql = insert.str();

/* Execute SQL statement */
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
}else{
fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
}
return;     

}
```

I keep getting an error
    error: cannot convert `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' to`char*' in assignment

How can I make this block of code work?

Is there any easier way to implement this? This is a project which requires C++ and any kind of database (MySQL,etc.)

Ok so here's the full code, this is a college project and I really need a bit of help to solve this http://pastebin.com/XiisxBxf

Comment: `rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.data(), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);`

Comment: Hello SQL injection attack

Comment: @jrok: Better use `c_str()`, to be sure it's terminated C-style.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `c_str()` member function of `std::string` to get a pointer to a zero-terminated character sequence, suitable for passing to C-style functions:

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
                         ^^^^^^^^
```

By the way, what happens if I give my name as `"); DROP TABLE ADBOOK #"`? Never insert user-provided strings directly into queries; [prepare](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) a statement with placeholders to [bind](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) to the input.

Also, round my way, neither phone numbers nor post/zipcodes can be represented by integers.