# Why is the error E0413 occurring in system() in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string content = "video.mp4";
    //error occurring on the line beneath
    system("cd C:\\Users\\amans\\Documents && " + content);
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand to why I'm getting the error E0413 = `no suitable conversion function from "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>" to "const char *" exists media_maker c : \Users\amans\Documents\code\maker.cpp   50` at the system(). Please Help

Comment: Have you tried `content.c_str()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ SQLite cannot convert \`std::basic\_string<char, std::char\_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' to \`char\*' in assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703275/c-sqlite-cannot-convert-stdbasic-stringchar-stdchar-traitschar-std)

Comment: BTW, a `cd` inside a `system` is likely to keep your [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) unchanged.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes I'm aware of that. I have to make a program which works with number of directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have this error because you code mixes string and const char* (wich isn't your fault) and there can only be implicit convertion from const char* to string but not the other way
so you need to make the convertion using std::string::c_str

```
system(("cd C:\\Users\\amans\\Documents && " + content).c_str());
```

Comment: Code-only answers not recommended. At least a brief explanation is recommended.

Comment: The cast is redundant, result of `std::string::operator+` is already `std::string`